# Customizing tracing in clojure

Tags: clojure

How can I inject custom code into the clojure tracing library? (https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace)

The library is producing traces like this:
(see [Debugging in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352020/debugging-in-clojure))

```
TRACE t4328: (fib 3)
TRACE t4329: | (fib 2)
TRACE t4330: | | (fib 1)
TRACE t4330: | | => 1
TRACE t4331: | | (fib 0)
TRACE t4331: | | => 0
TRACE t4329: | => 1
TRACE t4332: | (fib 1)
TRACE t4332: | => 1
TRACE t4328: => 2
```

I am particularly interested in:

- measuring the time of an invocation
- rendering of the input/output data.
- redirect the output

Examples of what I would like to produce:

```
Measure time:
TRACE t4328: (fib 3) (100 ms)
TRACE t4329: | (fib 2) (200 ms)
TRACE t4330: | | (fib 1) (150 ms)
.....

Rendering: Custom rendering per arg/return value
TRACE t4328: (fib number) (a small number was given)
TRACE t4329: | (fib number) (an even number was returned)
TRACE t4330: | | (fib number) (attention: number is too big)

Stacktrace:
(fib number) (fib.clj line 1)
| (fib number) (fib.clj line 2)
| | (fib number) (fib.clj line ...)

output to disk:
(fib 3)
| (fib 2)
| | (fib 1)
| | => 1
```

I am not sure if the library was designed to allow such customizations, however since the whole lib is merely a single file (https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/trace.clj), I don't mind to patch it directly.

A question from 2010 ([clojure: adding a debug trace to every function in a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346382/clojure-adding-a-debug-trace-to-every-function-in-a-namespace)) is similar, but the suggested answer uses a custom version of  `trace-ns`.
There the custom code is injected manually:

```
(clojure.contrib.trace/trace (str "entering: " s))
```

In short: Is there a more generic way today to inject my custom code?

Comment: Considered Robert Hooke by technomancy? https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke You wouldn't have to patch `tools.trace` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into it. The latest commit is 1 year old, do you think it's still adivisable to use?

Comment: The robert-hooke library is actually quite simple in its implementation and in the functionality it provides, which is very useful. [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/project.clj#L9) uses it (to enable users [modify built-in tasks](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/ff403992e414d86e2b9b775dce6a179bc21d3944/doc/PLUGINS.md#hooks)) so I would say that the reason why it hasn't had any commits lately, is because it is pretty solid already.