# Easily adding trace statements to LISP dialects (without using do for example)

Tags: clojure, lisp

When one is programming in an imperative programming languages such as Java one can conveniently add trace statements. For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  // do something
  // do something
  System.out.println("Some trace statement");
  // do something 
}
```

How does one accomplish this in a LISP dialect such as Clojure - for example say I wanted to add a trace just before recur:

```
(def fact
  (fn [n]
    (loop [cnt n acc 1]
       (if (zero? cnt)
            acc
          ;; say I want to add a trace here
          (recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt))))))
```

Notes:

1. The method should be relatively as simple as adding a line
2. For example if I were to use a do block -- I have to reformat, make sure I close the brackets appropriately

Comment: So you don't want to use `do` because of reformatting? What editor are you using?

Comment: @Chiron, my point is that I know how to solve this issue using a do -- however I always feel it is more trouble than I'd like -- I did a lot of LISP in my youth but I've never found a convenient way to be able to add trace statements to my code.

Comment: @Chiron, these days I'm trying light table, but other editors are vi and eclipse.

Comment: @NielsK: just be realistic. If one can't write a `do` statement because there might be a bracket error, then don't program in Lisp. Has nothing to do with *supremacist* or *toxic*. It's just advice which saves him a lot of trouble. There are people on Stackoverflow asking fake questions like these.

Comment: @NielsK That is not a valid argument. What about: "I don't want to add `if` condition to my Java code because I don't want to reformat my code" ?

Comment: @NielsK git checkout .

Comment: Although Spyscope looks like the promising answer, the OP might look into seeing if there's a paredit plugin for their editor. Paredit is all about making adding new statements to LISPs without introducing bracket errors

Comment: @C.WarrenDale I edited my answer so that Paredit stands out a little more

Comment: @coredump Thanks! I didn't notice until after I'd made the comment, and I forgot to edit it because I am a poor netizen ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Non-invasive tracing

Lisp environments generally provide interactive debugging environment and trace mechanisms.
For example, in SBCL, you could use the [**trace macro**](http://www.sbcl.org/1.0/manual/Function-Tracing.html):
*you don't even need to modify your code*, like you did in your Java example.

For Clojure, look at the [tools.trace library](http://clojure.github.io/tools.trace/), or the following answer: [clojure: adding a debug trace to every function in a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346382/clojure-adding-a-debug-trace-to-every-function-in-a-namespace)

### Custom functions and macros

See also the many answers to this question: [Debugging in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352020/debugging-in-clojure)
Most of them involve nesting the expression you want to debug/trace inside another expression, like *Chiron* suggested.

I don't think that "*I have to reformat and close the brackets appropriately*" is a good argument; everytime you edit your program you have to deal with the syntax, or else you won't ever modify your code.

### Paredit

<del>I personally don't use</del> I am now a happy user of [Paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit). Your editor keep track of parens and brackets while you code, which is quite handy.

### Reader macros

I you really don't want to nest your expression inside another one, I suppose you could write a reader macro so that you could *annotate* an expression with a debug statement, but this is overkill, imho (**edit**: this is what [spyscope](https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spyscope) does, apparently; see NielsK's answer).

Comment: TRACE is a macro, not a function.

Answer (score 5):

The [Spyscope](https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spyscope) library provides a simple option for putting in trace prints without having to change the original syntax, just in the way you (and many others) prefer.

```
spyscope.repl=> (take 20 (repeat #spy/p (+ 1 2 3)))
6
(6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6)
```

There's also ways of including trace messages

```
spyscope.repl=> #spy/d ^{:marker "triple-add"} (+ 1 2 3)
spyscope.repl$eval3935.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1) triple-add (+ 1 2 3) => 6
6
```

and even (partial) stack traces

```
spyscope.repl=> (take 20 (repeat #spy/d ^{:fs 3} (+ 1 2 3)))
----------------------------------------
clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
spyscope.repl$eval675.invoke(REPL:13) (+ 1 2 3) => 6
(6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `do` block:

```
(def fact
(fn [n]
(loop [cnt n acc 1]
   (if (zero? cnt)
        acc
      (do
        (println "**")
        (recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt)))))))

user=> (fact 4)
**
**
**
**
24
```

In your REPL:

```
(doc do)
```

> do
>     (do exprs*)
>   Special Form
>     Evaluates the expressions in order and returns the value of
>     the last. If no expressions are supplied, returns nil.
>       Please see http://clojure.org/special_forms#do

Comment: Thank your for your Answer however I was looking for a more convenient form than adding a do block -- I'll update my question

Comment: For possible viewers. Original question didn't mention that the OP doesn't want to use `do` block. It was updated later.

Answer (score 1):

I have several macros that allow something like this (because it is handy not having to toss in a progn many times):

(my-trace ("hi mom" 1 2 3) recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt))

my-trace simply expands into:

(progn
      (imperative-trace "hi mom" 1 2 3)
      (recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt)))

a simpler variant is:

(echo hi-mom recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt))

which captures the result of the wrapped form and prints it tagged with hi-mom.

A nicety is that I can insert/remove nil as the unevaluated first parameter to turn tracing off/on. On some debug out put I just leave the trace in place but disabled until the next time I need it.

-hk

Comment: What language is that?  `progn` looks like Common Lisp.  `recur` looks like Clojure.